# Why do these two functions in Clojure have different output?

Tags: clojure

Why those two functions have a different return?

```
(filter (and #(= (rem % 2) 1)
             #(= (rem % 3) 0)) 
          (take 100 (iterate inc 0)))  ;=> (0 3 6 9 12... 

(filter #(and (= (rem % 2) 1) 
              (= (rem % 3) 0)) 
          (take 100 (iterate inc 0)))  ;=> (3 9 15 21...
```

Is the form with two anonymous functions valid?

Comment: Small note:  Instead of `(take 100 (iterate inc 0))` just use `(range 100)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the other answer...

You have accidentally discovered a "feature" of Clojure which, IMHO, causes more trouble than it is worth.

### What is "truthy" in Clojure?

Consider what Clojure considers "truthy":

```
(defn truthy?
  [x]
  (if x
    :yes
    :no))

(dotest
  (is= :yes (truthy? true))
  (is= :yes (truthy? 1))
  (is= :yes (truthy? :a))

  (is= :no (truthy? nil))
  (is= :no (truthy? false)))
```

Note that a function object is also "truthy":

```
(dotest 
  (let [fn-obj-1 (fn [x] (+ x 1)) 
        fn-obj-2        #(+ % 1)]  ; shorthand, equiv to fn-obj-1
    (is= :yes (truthy? fn-obj-1))
    (is= :yes (truthy? fn-obj-2))
    (is= 42 (fn-obj-1 41))  ; call the fn
    (is= 42 (fn-obj-2 41))  ; call the fn
  ))
```

### The "tricky" result of the `and` macro

The `and` macro ([source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L842)) doesn't just return a boolean value as you may expect. Instead, it returns the item that "caused" the result:

```
(dotest 
  (is= 3     (and 1 2 3))      ; 1
  (is= :a    (and 99 :a))      ; 2

  (is= nil   (and nil :a))     ; 3
  (is= false (and false 88)))  ; 4
```

So if all the items are "truthy", `and` returns the last one since it is the "deciding factor" (cases 1 & 2).  If one or more "falsey" values are present, `and` returns the first one found since it is the "deciding factor" (cases 3 & 4).

Personally, I never use this feature of Clojure. IMHO it is something of a "trick" that makes code difficult to decipher correctly.

### How does the `and` macro work?

In order to return the "deciding factor" to you, the `and` macro expands into code like this:

```
; (and 99 :a)
(let [x 99]
  (if x 
    ; recursive invocation: (and :a)
    x))
```

So if the `99` had been false or nil instead, it would have been returned to you.  Since `99` is truthy, `and` recurses with the next value `:a` as follows:

```
; (and :a)
:a
```

Since there is only 1 item in this recursion level, it must be the "deciding factor" and the `and` macro just returns the raw value to you.

### Remember that `and` is a macro

This means it runs at compile time (every macro is properly regarded as a "compiler extension").  In your first case, your code looks like so:

```
(filter (and f1 f2) ...)
```

where `f1` and `f2` are both functions.  Since both are "truthy?", `and` returns the last item to you.  Since the above code rewriting with `let` etc occurs at compile time, your code gets converted into:

```
(filter 
  (let [x f1]
    (if x 
      f2
      f1))
  ...)
```

And since `f1` is truthy, that simplifies to

```
(filter 
  f2
  ...)
```

where `f2` is just `#(= (rem % 3) 0)`.  So we see [0 3 6 ...] returned.

---

### Final Answer

Because of a Clojure "quirk", your first `filter` does not generate a compiler error (although I think it should).  The 2nd form does what you want, since `filter`  expects exactly 1 function to use in deciding which items are retained.

---

The above is based on [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
(and #(= (rem % 2) 1) #(= (rem % 3) 0))
```

is the same as just writing the following:

```
#(= (rem % 3) 0))
```

This is because `and` returns the first parameter that is `false` or `nil`. If there are none, it returns the last parameter.

If you want to combine two functions, you can use [every-pred](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/every-pred):

```
(every-pred #(= (rem % 2) 1) #(= (rem % 3) 0))
```

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for `and` to return the *first* truthy value - it needs to make sure that, if there are any falsey values, it can return one of those. So if all the values are truthy, it returns the last one, not the first. You can see this in action in the question: the function being used as predicate is the second one, not the first.

Comment: you are right, thanks for the clarification. I was mixing it up with the `or` macro. Corrected my answer accordingly.